# What is the fastest way to extract a json from a data.table

Tags: r, json, performance, data.table

We've got a json inside a data.table which we need to extract from its column and put their values into columns.

The json looks as follows:

```
# 13B = index, 
# 132 = value
# s = column with value 6.48, i = column with value 0
# {
#   "13B": [132, {"s": 6.48} ],
#   "12B": [660, {}],
#   "15B": [-1, {"i": 0, "v": 0}]
# }
```

The code to generate a test dataset, of course the values inside the json differ per index:

```
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
df <- iris[1:5, c(1,5)]
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt$Sepal.Length <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df$Jason <-  '{"13B":[132,{"s":6.48}],"12B":[660,{}],"15B":[-1,{"i":0,"v":0}]}'
dt$Jason[3] <- "{\"13B\":[132,{\"s\":1.46}],\"12B\":[987,{}],\"18E\":[12,{\"i\":0,\"v\":8}]}"


#> dt
#   Sepal.Length Species                                                            Jason
#1:            1  setosa {"13B":[132,{"s":6.48}],"12B":[660,{}],"15B":[-1,{"i":0,"v":0}]}
#2:            2  setosa {"13B":[132,{"s":6.48}],"12B":[660,{}],"15B":[-1,{"i":0,"v":0}]}
#3:            3  setosa {"13B":[132,{"s":1.46}],"12B":[987,{}],"18E":[12,{"i":0,"v":8}]}
#4:            4  setosa {"13B":[132,{"s":6.48}],"12B":[660,{}],"15B":[-1,{"i":0,"v":0}]}
#5:            5  setosa {"13B":[132,{"s":6.48}],"12B":[660,{}],"15B":[-1,{"i":0,"v":0}]}
```

We've got this project running with a for loop which is very slow. We will eventually have millions of rows in our table thus speed is very important.

I had the idea to loop through our dataset once, and assign the values of the json to a predefined data.table in a new column, after which we could transform the data to be in our desired format. But I believe there must be faster options in data.table which I cannot think of right now.

The final dt is supposed to look like this:

[image]

**What would be the fastest way in data.table to extract our json (which is nested inside a data.table) to a column for the different values?**

Comment: Did you try `jsonlite::fromJSON`? e.g., `jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("[", paste(dt$Jason, collapse = ","), "]"))`